# Where clause doesn't work on Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, select, where-clause

I'm new in Android. I'm trying to get a specific word from database (SQLite). But I couldn't make where clause work. Where am I making mistake?
My code is it:

```
    private String[] sutunlar = {"ingilizce","turkce"};

public void kelimeUret() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = kelimeler.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor kayit = db.query("kelimeler", sutunlar, "ingilizce='hello'", null, null, null, null);

    String sonuc = kayit.getString(0);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sonuc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I can not get a result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `kayit.moveToFirst()` before calling `kayit.getString(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
  private String[] sutunlar = {"ingilizce","turkce"};
    public void kelimeUret() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = kelimeler.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor kayit = db.query("kelimeler", sutunlar, "ingilizce='hello'", null, null, null, null);
    if (kayit.moveToFirst())
        {
        String sonuc = kayit.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sonuc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    kayit.close();
}
```